# How to set max jsonresult limit for web api

Tags: c#

I am returning json result as below via web api ,This works fine but

```
JsonResult(null) { Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
```

when at client side using below code and when of size  josn is more than 45 mb it does not work

```
string jsontable = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var unwrappedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsontable);
dt= (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(unwrappedJson, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "does not work"? Does it throw an exception? Can you check the payload in text for before desserializing and see if the contents match your expectation?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you should avoid using `.Result` whenever possible. Use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` instead.

Comment: jsontable  comes and null is the issue. Since jsontable   is null no data is returned,

Comment: Also, by manually serializing the value like what you are doing, you are basically throwing away the actual functionality of `JsonResult`. Can you try just doing `return JsonResult(dt);`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.